# Move matching rows along with parent row on drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I want to move matching rows along with "parent" row when dragging and dropping.

I have the following code.

```
<table id="sortable">
  <tr data-node-id="1">
    <td>Parent node 1</td>
    <td>Elements of parent node 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-pid="1">
    <td>Child node 1</td>
    <td>Elements of child node 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-id="2">
    <td>Parent node 2</td>
    <td>Elements of parent node 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-node-pid="2">
    <td>Child node 2</td>
    <td>Elements of child node 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery which I have :

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        onUpdate: function (evt) {

        },
    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Your example doesn't have any "child" rows.  Do you mean "matching" rows where they all have the same `date-node-pid`?

Comment: yes I mean matching rows